# Docker container published via port forward can't connect to its own published port

Tags: docker, routes

I have a docker container with an apache server on port 80. Port 8000 of the docker host is being forwarded to 80 in the container. Our application needs to connect to itself to use a web service. This connection URL is determined at runtime based on the URL the user is using to access the application. However, when it tries to connect to the host's IP address on port 8000, connection fails. Debugging with telnet and tracepath indicate routing error. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Turns out issue was that there was no firewall rule on the host allowing for access to the published port from the inside network.

Answer (score 0):

The likely root cause here, is you're listening on the wrong interface in your container.

If you bind `localhost:80` then you *cannot* access that using "publish". You need to bind `0.0.0.0:80` (or `*:80` or whatever your config supports) and then it'll work.